# PyCharm - Recover Corrupted Project

Tags: pycharm

My system OS got corrupted and I'm unable to login to the system. I have a hard drive of the system. Is there a way to recover the project. I see below files alone,

[image]

Comment: I don't think those are project files, but instead IDE wide configurations/history. Whatever was project specific will be in the directory where the project's source code was, and project specific settings will be inside the `.idea` folder inside the project directory. Good luck getting your data back.

Comment: I don't see any files under .idea, the project folder itself is corrupted

Comment: You can see for yourself in [Locations of directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html) and also at [Directories used by the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) that all those directories are system settings. I've never seen a case of the source code being duplicated nor cached elsewhere by the IDE.